# s3 cloudformation always gives rollback and no s3 bucket create

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

Other resources such as EC2 create with no issue but can't create a PublicRead s3 bucket.

```
Resources:
  MyS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: helloworldwebsite
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        IndexDocument: index.html
```

The command is:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name myteststack --template-body "file:///path/to/S3-template.yaml"
```

Here is the screenshot of the CloudFormation / Stacks:

[image]

Comment: Go to the **Events** tab and look in the last column for the cause of the rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is correct. The only possible issue is that bucket name `helloworldwebsite` **already exists**. Bucket names must be **globally unique** across all regions and accounts. Thus, please change the `BucketName` to something new, e.g.:

```
Resources:
  MyS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: helloworldwebsite222232111
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        IndexDocument: index.html
```